# Undefined reference using Taglib with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, taglib

I can't get Taglib to work with Qt on Windows 10 64bits but I can with GNU/Linux 64bits.

[image]

I successfuly managed to build Taglib as explain in their manual with cmake and the compiler provided by Qt (`C:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin\`) and the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

Then with the shell provided by Qt for MinGW 7.3.0 64bits I can run `mingw32-make` to build it.
With `mingw32-make install` I have everything I need in `C:\Program Files (x86)\taglib\` the .a and .h files (no .dll?).

.pro file generated using the tool to add external libraries in Qt Creator :

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/taglib/lib/' -llibtag

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/taglib/include'
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/'../../../../../Program Files (x86)/taglib/include'
```

cpp code :

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    TagLib::FileRef f("Latex Solar Beef.mp3");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the

```
DEFINES += TAGLIB_STATIC
```

Problem solved